# I got error when running OPNet project

Tags: c++, opnet

It's my first time working with opnet.

I got this error:

> <<< Recoverable Error >>>
>
> Object repository construction failed
> External code file (C:\opnet\14.5.A\models\std\umts\umts_support.ex.c)
> compilation failed, see error messages in (C:\Users\Niloofar\op_admin\tmp\cc_err_4952)
> T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE), PROC (sim_load_repos_rebuild)

Comment: have you even bothered to read this?

Answer (score 2):

`Edit > Preferences` ... Type `repositories` and search ... in the result there will be Network Simulation Repositories ... click on the values box ... then a new window will pop up ... press Insert and type `stdmod` ... after you do that click OK

if you the OK button is deactivated ... just make click on white area and it will be activated ... I hope this helps